# Need help understanding try catch exception handling in WinRT/CPP within a custom C++ library

Tags: windows, exception, c++-winrt

I am using the a SQLite wrapper library in a WinRT/CPP project from

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6343/CppSQLite-C-Wrapper-for-SQLite

since the wrapper throws a custom exception, looks like the WINRT system just aborts the app rather than propagating the exception to my catch block (I think), which means something like this

```
try {
       execDML("insert into...");
}

catch (exception e)
{
   //exception message
}
```

Does not work and results in program abort

When I run this in a debugger looks like the runtime exception handler ends up at this point

```
if (!IsInExceptionSpec(pExcept, T::getESTypes(pFuncInfo))) // code in frame.cpp invoked on exception
```

I am guessing there must be some way of registering an exception handler with the runtime system to allow custom exceptions to be handled within the code vs aborting?

I guess I could rewrite the wrapper to return error codes, if there is no way of registering an exception handler - however would like to understand if that is indeed the case here...

Comment: A fair bit of confusion here: The Windows Runtime doesn't know what exceptions are. In the Windows Runtime there are only `HRESULT` codes, some of which map to error conditions. Those errors are translated by C++/WinRT into C++ exceptions. If you need to set up a C++ exception handler, then there's nothing magical here: It can only be set up in a caller. If you need to convert C++ exceptions into `HRESULT` codes, then [`to_hresult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/error-handling/to-hresult) can do that. It's lossy, and custom exception types won't survive.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - your comment forced me to look more closely at the root cause in my case and it turns out the library was throwing a specific class exception - once I changed my catch block to the specific exception class (rather than generic exception) it works. Really appreciate your explanation